# django url follow folder system

Tags: python, django, url

Is it possible to make URL in Django to follow folder path like in GitHub, Dropbox

```
https://github.com/<username>/<path>/<path>/<file>
```

Currently, I am doing it like this

```
re_path(r'^.*', myview)
```

then using the `split('/')` function in view

Is there is a batter way to do that?

The functionality of the website is that you can create a folder and inside that folder, you can either create another new folder or create a file.

Let's say if you create a folder called python and create a file in this folder called list, then the URL must be like this

```
www.bla-bla.com/python/list/
```

And if you create a new folder in the python folder called "data type" and create a file "list" in "data type" folder then the URL must look like this

```
www.bla-bla.com/python/data-type/list/
```

Just to make URL more SEO friendly.

Thanks

Comment: Try `path("<username>/<path>/path2/file_id")` and on your view: `def view(request, username, path, path2, file_id):`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand what is your problem. When designing a web app you gotta create routes and then from inside of the functions to handle each route you render w/e html file you want. Example

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#targetText=A%20view%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Ctype,page%20for%20a%20single%20entry.

that's how it's done in flask -  https://hackersandslackers.com/the-art-of-building-flask-routes/#targetText=Flask%20contains%20a%20built%2Din,a%20function%20containing%20route%20logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added an example like what I am trying to achieve to make the question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the best way to do this is:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<username>/<path>/<filename>/', views.file, name='file'),
]
```

views.py

```
def file(request, username, path, filename):
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added an example like what I am trying to achieve to make the question more understandable.